# Delphi 6 update 2 error

Tags: delphi, updates

I just bought a new laptop (a 64 bits one running Win8.1) and I thought it would be best if I use a virtual machine for my main programming environment.

I managed to install Delphi 6 Enterprise Edition but I am no longer able to install Update #2. I am getting this strange error stating that I need to install Update #2 before updating the file:

[image]

I only need to run the runtime library. The general update works, but I can't use my files (especially Indy) because they were compiled with a different file version.

I tried all workarounds. If I click No, the update technically happens, but I still get the message. I tried to manipulate the registries, but this still doesn't work. As I mentioned, the general update will not let me compile my project.

Has anyone ever encountered such an error?

Comment: You *are* running as administrator, I suppose? And did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198603/delphi-6-ide-and-apps-working-on-windows-7-64-bit ?

Comment: We don't really know what you've done. You tried to manipulate the registries? No idea what that means. So long as the install directory is writeable by standard user then D6 is trivial to install, update and run.

Comment: Hi David. Obviously it makes sense in my head, but I didn't express it correctly. So I am using this VM and I knew since my last attempt to install Update 2 that there might be some problems, I took a snapshot. I kept reverting to this snapshot (of a clean Delphi 6 installation) and attempted to a) do a simple update of RTL#2 - which always worked before b) do an update running as admin c) clicking No in the dialog box above, completing the rtl install then installing the packages that require Update 2 - which doesn't work d) fudge the registry (adding the Update #2 entry as true) then c)

Comment: Which also didn't work. So I either get this message and stop or ignore it and then it becomes impossible to install other packages

Answer (score 2):

Note from [download side :](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38607)
`You must install General Update 2 below in order to run the Delphi 6 Runtime Library Update 2.`

you should install

- 1.) **D6_upd2_ent.exe** (Basic Update before install `del6_ent_rtl2`) !
- 2.) **del6_ent_rtl2.exe**

I don't know where you are getting `D6_RTL2_ENT.exe` from ?

Delphi 6 Update 2

**Readme**  [Delphi 6 Update 2](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28405)

**Third-party and add-on package issues**

Some third-party and add-on packages may generate errors after installing Delphi 6 Update Pack 2.

If you encounter any such errors, uninstall the third-party package in Delphi6 (Component| Install Packages, select the package, click remove, and rebuild), and contact the third-party package provider for an updated package.

Related note: The functionality previously available in InvWiz60.bpl, a free
add-on package installed by many Delphi 6 users, is installed with this update. If you previously installed InvWiz60, you should uninstall it to avoid conflicts with
the new built-in functionality.

**Update :**

OP
**I am getting this strange error stating that I need to install Update #2 before updating the file:**

The error message is normal if you try to install `update rtl 2` without the necessary `General update 2` to install.

You ask us about a strange error and ignore the installations instructions

**You must install General Update 2 below in order to run the Delphi 6 Runtime Library Update 2**.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the package del6_ent_rtl2.exe from http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38607 , so directly from the source. The thing is that I only want to install this one. The general update messes with my project because I can't build it anymore (I get an error on IndyIOHandler as it "was compiled with a different version of ...") I guess I will be forced to pursue that one if this doesn't work, as it did so many times before. The problem with Indy is that I can't recompile it for some reason for Delphi 6 :(

Comment: @cleantone : from the picture in your question we can see you use a file `D6_RTL2_ENT` !

Comment: Yes, sometime along the way, I erroneously changed the name of the file. The one I try to install is the smaller sized of the 2 (the names are rather confusing indeed). In conclusion, the file name is wrong on my machine, I am trying to install del6_ent_rtl2.exe and I get the error in the Original Post

Comment: I guess my only option now is to do the general update and then ask a new question on the compiled with the version issue :(

Comment: @cleantone : That is absolutely correct and do not forget the `indy Tag`.

Comment: In the end, I fixed that by applying Update3. I am a little bit surprised but happy none the less